# Robovm Local notifications not showing up. Scheduling seems successful. Am I missing something?

Tags: java, ios, libgdx, robovm

I am trying to get local/scheduled notifications working. With push messages (using Parse) working fine I though local would be easy, but even though the registration seems to go fine (didRegisterUserNotificationSettings is fired) and the scheduling seems to work too, the notification does not show up. I have tested on iOS 7 (iphone 4) and iOS 9 (iphone simulator). What am I missing?

here is my code:

```
@Override
public boolean didFinishLaunching(UIApplication application,UIApplicationLaunchOptions launchOptions)    
{
 boolean retval = super.didFinishLaunching(application, launchOptions);
 //some other stuff happens here regarding parse push. But since this works I have cut it out
 registerForPush();
 return retval;

}


public void registerForPush()
{
 if (IOSLauncher.getOSMajorVersion() >= 8)
 {
 UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = UIUserNotificationType.with(UIUserNotificationType.Alert, UIUserNotificationType.Badge, UIUserNotificationType.Sound);


 UIUserNotificationSettings settings = new UIUserNotificationSettings(userNotificationTypes, null);
 application.registerUserNotificationSettings(settings);
 application.registerForRemoteNotifications();
 }
 else
 {
 UIRemoteNotificationType type = UIRemoteNotificationType.with(UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert, UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge, UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound);
 application.registerForRemoteNotificationTypes(type);
 }
}


public void scheduleNotification(String title, String text, Date date, int ID)
{
    UILocalNotification notification = new UILocalNotification();
    if(getOSMajorVersion() >= 8 && getOSMinorVersion() >= 2)
    notification.setAlertTitle(title);
    notification.setAlertBody(text);
    notification.setFireDate(new NSDate(date));
 NSMutableDictionary<NSObject, NSObject> dict = new NSMutableDictionary<>();
 dict.put("id",NSNumber.valueOf(ID));
 notification.setUserInfo(dict);
    UIApplication.getSharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification);
}
```

Edit:
After settting the notification it is present in the array returned by:

```
UIApplication.getSharedApplication.getScheduledLocalNotifications();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved after Adding:

```
notification.setTimeZone(NSTimeZone.getLocalTimeZone());
```

and setting the expire time of my test timer from 1 minute to 5 minutes
I'm not sure which is the actual solution, but the problem is gone, so I'm happy!

EDIT:

```
UILocalNotification notification = new UILocalNotification();
notification.setAlertTitle("title");
notification.setAlertBody("text");

NSMutableDictionary<NSObject, NSObject> dict = new NSMutableDictionary<>();
//add any customer stuff to your dictionary here
notification.setUserInfo(dict);
notification.setFireDate(new NSDate(date));         //date is some date in the future. Make sure it is in the correct TZ. If it does not work, try to make it at least 5 minutes in the future. I remember this helping my situation
notification.setTimeZone(NSTimeZone.getLocalTimeZone());
UIApplication.getSharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(notification);
```

Comment: Would you mind sharing the code? I'm trying to generate the notifications, but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: I've added a snippet of my working code. It was already mostly in the OP though